# Woocommerce, display and refresh total checkout on the same page without refresh page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, express-checkout

I have e-shop (Wordpress with WooCommerce) with only home page, which contains product and ajax button add to cart and the checkout on the same page, but the checkout doesn't refresh with new item.

How to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: the only code we have write it's the button, on the click button href="http://host/home/?add_to_cart=44&add-to-cart=44" and the checkout with shortcode [woocommerce_checkout], we have enable ajax option in settings woocommerce

Comment: Is it supposed to refresh (is it broken)? Or do you WANT it to refresh and don't know how to? Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Comment: It's supposse to refresh if we active ajax button setting, and it's activate but doesn't work, no error in console or logs woocommerce